# Question about finding slope from my textbook, walking through linear regression through the least squares method (pre-calculus)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, least-squares, linear-regression

I have question about a specific step describing how to do linear regression with the least squares method. In the textbook, it says that you need to find  $\triangle x$ and $\triangle y$ (which are $x  -  \bar{x}$ and $y  -  \bar{y}$) then you multiply each one together, and find $\Sigma  \triangle x \triangle y$. You then go on to divide this by $ \Sigma  (\triangle x)^{2} $

$\frac {\Sigma  \triangle x \triangle y}{\Sigma  (\triangle x)^{2}}  $

Which is the slope of the linear regression line

I'm guessing multiplying $\triangle x$ and $\triangle y$ means you're finding the area of the square the actual coordinates make

but then $(\triangle x)^{2}$ means you're finding the supposed, or standard size of what the squares should be? (based on the x values you have)

then the slope is the ratio between them, giving you the line of best fit

Am I understanding this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

**Derivation**

We wish to find the slope $m$ from the following linear equations. Keep in mind that each equation has its error $\epsilon$

$$
\Delta y_{i} = m\Delta x_{i}+\epsilon_{i} 
$$

When we do least square regression, we select $m$ that minimize the sum of squared errors:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i}\epsilon_{i}^{2}&=\sum_{i}\left(\Delta y_{i}-m\Delta x_{i}\right)^{2}
\\
&=
m^{2}\sum_{i}\left(\Delta x_{i}\right)^{2}-2m\sum_{i}\Delta x_{i}\Delta y_{i}+\sum_{i}\left(\Delta y_{i}\right)^{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

Notice that the RHS is a quadratic polynomial in $m$ with positive first coefficient. The $m$ that minimize the quadratic equation is given by:

$$
m=\frac{\sum_{i}\Delta x_{i}\Delta y_{i}}{\sum_{i}\left(\Delta x_{i}\right)^{2}}
$$

**Some Intuition**

Multiply the initial linear equation by $\Delta x_{i}$ and sum for all values of $i$:

$$
\sum_{i}\Delta x_{i}\Delta y_{i}=m\sum_{i}\left(\Delta x_{i}\right)^{2}+\sum_{i}\Delta x_{i}\epsilon_{i}
$$

When we substitute the $m$ values we obtain

$$
0=\sum_{i}\Delta x_{i}\epsilon_{i}
$$

One interpretation is: the least square regression choose the slope such that the errors $\epsilon$ are uncorrelated with the regressors $\Delta x$.